# Can't add "onclick" function to div element javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can't add function to element `javascript`

the function `modalbg.onclick` not work.

```
var modalbg = document.createElement("div");

document.body.appendChild(modalbg); // to place at end of document
    modalbg.onclick(function () {
       alert();
})
```

**Error is:**

> (index):625 Uncaught TypeError: modalbg.onclick is not a function(…)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax:

```
modalbg.onclick(function () {
            alert();
        })
```

is wrong, and the reported error-message explicitly tells you why it's wrong: `onclick` is not a function.

The appropriate syntax, if you must use `onclick` is:

```
modalbg.onclick = function () {
        alert();
      };
```

Although I'd strongly advise you to move away from `onclick` event-handlers, and use `EventTarget.addEventListener()` instead, to give:

```
modalbg.addEventListener('click', alert);
```

Or:

```
modalbg.addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert();
});
```

References:

- [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve this by adding `Event Listener` to `DOM` element.

```js
var modalbg = document.createElement("div");

        document.body.appendChild(modalbg); // to place at end of document
        modalbg.innerHTML = "click me";
        modalbg.addEventListener('click', function () {
            alert("Hai");
        })
```